# How to load the specific country name dropdwon in admin side magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Basically when i add below code in system.xml file it load all the countries in admin side

```
<field id="showmethod" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Show Method if Not Applicable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <frontend_class>shipping-skip-hide</frontend_class>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="active">1</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
```

but i want to get only one country in dropdown .Is there any way to do this?

Comment: for that instead of using Core source model, create you own source model with the required array

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, Please change the labels as per the requirement

**In your System.xml**

```
<field id="showmethod" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="80" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
<label>Show Method if Not Applicable</label>
                    <source_model>{Namespace}\{Module}\Model\Config\Source\CountryList</source_model>
                    <frontend_class>shipping-skip-hide</frontend_class>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="active">1</field>
                    </depends>
 </field>
```

**In Your custom module under app/code/{Namespace}/{Module}/Model/Config/source/**

```
<?php 
namespace {Namespace}\{Module}\Model\Config\source;

class CountryList implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
 public function toOptionArray()
 {
  return [
    ['value' => 'USA', 'label' => __('USA')]    
  ];
 }
}
```